# Working Zoom/Pan example with D3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get this example working (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340) but getting an error (below). The code I'm trying to run is exactly the same as what is at the link with one exception, had to modify the json location as I didn't serve the json file locally.

I've been trying several topojson examples as well and getting errors with those too. I'm not sure if it's an API version issue or what. Any ideas how to get this working or could someone enlighten me as to how to debug this issue?  I'm pretty new to D3.

update: error added

```
   GET http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json
    200 OK
            1.29s   
    d3.v3.min.js (line 1)
    TypeError: us is undefined
    [Break On This Error]   
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
```

update: code added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.background {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#states {
  fill: #aaa;
}

#state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1070)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate(projection.translate())
    .scale(projection.scale())
    .scaleExtent([height, 8 * height])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .call(zoom);

g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json", function(error, us) {
  g.append("g")
      .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", clicked);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("id", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path);
});

function clicked(d) {
  var centroid = path.centroid(d),
      translate = projection.translate();

  projection.translate([
    translate[0] - centroid[0] + width / 2,
    translate[1] - centroid[1] + height / 2
  ]);

  zoom.translate(projection.translate());

  g.selectAll("path").transition()
      .duration(700)
      .attr("d", path);
}

function zoomed() {
  projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
  g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
}

</script>
```

Comment: This error is basically telling you that the JSON file isn't there.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json exists.

Comment: Are you using the right version of d3? It's going to be hard to help you if you don't post some code.

Comment: What does "error" contain?

Comment: Ok. code posted in original question -- along with error message. No idea if it's the correct d3 version but I would assume so as I pasted it right from bl.ocks website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the code on localhost, and referencing it the way you posted, then you'll get an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.

If you put the code on some gist, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks - that was it!  I downloaded the json file and placed it in the same directory as the example file and it worked.  So all of these json files need to be local to the javascript?

Comment: d3.json() is making a XMLHttpRequest (ajax request), and due to browser's same origin policy, you can only make a request to the same domain — I'm simplifying here. So, all your JSON files need to be on the same server; in this case, all on your localhost.